# Manipulate group/union of objects with corner path nodes in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, vector, path, isometric

I'm attempting to create an isometric view of a laptop with a code block on its screen (left picture). Each section is its own separate object that I can either group or form together as a union (I can ignore the colouring for now).

I would like to manipulate the group/union of sections together as one so that they can be adapted to the blue square on the right picture, essentially to treat the group as a square with corner nodes that can be independently moved. I'm not sure of how to achieve this, as in the Node edit tool each section has its own nodes conserved.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to tilt the screen backwards so that it matches the perspective of the blue square?  If so, you can use the Nodes Tool to select multiple nodes of multiple objects, and move them together as one. [see example here](https://imgur.com/ijwe7Up).

Comment: Not the screen, the code block in this case. I want to the code block to match the perspective of the blue square. The problem is the code block conserves EVERY node for each section, which makes it really difficult to manipulate the entire code block as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for Inkscape 1.3. I assume your code/text has already been converted to paths. If not, make sure it is by using *Object > Object to Path*

Then do the following:

1. Select the object using the Selector Tool <kbd>S</kbd>
2. In the Path Effects tab, search for perspective, and choose the Perspective/Envelope.  The shortcut to open the path effects tab is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>&</kbd>
3. Swicth to the Nodes Tool <kbd>S</kbd>, and click and drag the control points.

An example

[image]

Comment: That works! Thank you